# code coverage for static library(.lib) visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-libraries, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have a static library (.lib). my test cases in my test project are in visual studio, TCs refer to many static library function. the test cases works and everything goes well. but i cant get the code coverage for the code inside .lib, because i cant add an instrument .lib. Is there a way to get a code coverage for .lib too?

Answer (score 0):

If you have source code of the static library, you could use your current test project to test the functions in the lib. Just combine your test project with the project that generates the library in visual studio.
If you do not have source code, you could design test cases to perform black-box tests of this lib.

Comment: I have the source code for .lib and test project both and both are under same solution. The test cases also working fine. but the trouble is in getting the code coverage for .lib. cannot add .lib to instrument img for test project.

Answer (score -1):

I did a lot of experiments on this for my work and following are the observations.
The code instrumentation works at compile time. 
Meaning when the code is being compiled it is also being instrumented. So for gcc based instrumentation the `--ftest-coverage` and `--fprofile-arcs` flags comes into picture here. 
The static library is linked after the compilation is done so it is not getting instrumented. As it is not getting instrumented no data from it is being generated.

So next logical step I also instrumented the library code, compiled it and then generated the static library from that instrumented code.
Now as i understood the static library was made using an application tool called `ar` which in my case in my ide was automatically taking in the `.o` file. This previously was a non instrumented object file. Now after instrumentation expectation was that data from static library should also be flushed against each file in the library. But that didnt happen. 
This means one of the two things either 
1 - .gcno files also need to be added their or 
2 - Only files that are compiled will be able to generate the profile data.

Now the next step i did was modify this static library building step and made the following change. My original line was `ar rcs libmylib.a mylib.o` and i changed it to `ar rcs libmylib.a mylib.gcno`. Basically included the gcno file into the static library which obviously didnt work. But still gave it a shot.

Next i did was added both `.o` and `.gcno' both were included into the static library. Surprisingly the application ran without error but no profile data was generated. Which lead me to believe that profile data is generated only for the files that are compiled in the application and not the one that is linked.

Last attempt that i made is that instead of linking it as a static library archive i am directly attaching the object file into the application. `mylib.o` . This is already an instrumented object. But this already instrumented object is again added at linking time. So until and unless your code exists at the compile time the theory is profile data cannot be generated from it.

I am not sure of the dynamic link library. But above are my observation from the experiments that i performed.